# Query In google Apps Script - Arrayformula error

Tags: sql, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I have a misbehaving query in a google sheet ([here's a copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mXWl3s_yCEuRF3fGVQ0iZkGXqeXeVAHiVCBjNfYuXCw/edit?usp=sharing)). I'm using this sheet as a back end for user feedback (via a form), and forming a bug tracker/feature request sheet out of it, for a proprietary application.

The query in question is on the Master tab, Column G:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(FormResponses!D2:D = "Bug report",
    QUERY(FormResponses!A2:O, "SELECT E,F WHERE D ='Bug report'",0), 
  IF(FormResponses!D2:D = "Suggestion for Improvement", 
    QUERY(FormResponses!A2:O, "SELECT G,H WHERE D ='Suggestion for Improvement'",0),
  IF(FormResponses!D2:D = "Feature Request",
    QUERY(FormResponses!A2:O, "SELECT I WHERE D ='Feature Request'",0),
  IF(FormResponses!D2:D = "Other",
    QUERY(FormResponses!A2:O, "SELECT J WHERE D ='Other'",0), "")
))))
```

It works, until an second item comes in with the same category as something already there.

**Example:** someone submits a "bug report", there is already an item classified as a bug report in formResponses, the Master tab gives this error in the offending cell of column G : **"Array arguments to IF are of different size"**

What I need is for the formula look at the category in Column D of Master, and then pull the report and additional details data from "formResponses," that matches the line. I know that error is telling me exactly whats wrong :) but I can't find a way to fix it. What have I done this time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing my issue by using this code:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(FormResponses!D:D = "Bug report",
    QUERY(FormResponses!A:O, "SELECT E,F",0), 
  IF(FormResponses!D:D = "Suggestion for Improvement",
    QUERY(FormResponses!A:O, "SELECT G,H",0), 
  IF(FormResponses!D:D = "Feature Request", 
    QUERY(FormResponses!A:O, "SELECT I,K",0), 
  IF(FormResponses!D:D = "Other", 
    QUERY(FormResponses!A:O, "SELECT J,K",0),"")
))))
```

Best I can tell, I was both using too specific of a range with the A2:O, and doubling up on my parameters by using both an IF( statement and a WHERE statement to look for a specific string.

There is still a small issue here, where any Query that selects a single column (the two bottom IF's) will pull duplicate data into the two cells. I've worked around this by just having it pull an empty column for the second selector.

If anyone has any better methods, I'd be happy to hear them :)